# SARIMA forecast of economic variables with shocks of COVID-19

Tags: time-series, forecasting, accuracy, macroeconomics, covid-19

I am trying to fit a **SARIMA** model to a macroeconomic variable. However there is a **huge drop in 2020-March due to Covid-19** and after 3 months the drop has been recovered. So the MAPE is very low. How can I increase my forecast accuracy?  I am using python to do the coding. **If anyone knows the code/approach to use in such situations please share.**